# Solving an nonlinear ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

$$y'y'' = ky^2$$

I need a closed form expresion, if not atleast an almost closed form expression such as an inverse of an integral characterization. What could be the properties of its solutions?

Comment: The solution is in terms of [weierstrass p](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=weierstrassp) $\wp(x;0,b)$. From [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y’%28x%29%3Dsqrt%28k+y%5E3%2B+c%29), the hypergeometric function simplifies to an [inverse weierstrass function](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverseweierstrassp) and inverting gives the solution.

Answer (score 5):

What  about assuming a solution (boundary conditions permitting, you did not mention any) such as $$ y = e^{\beta x}$$
Then one gets $$ \beta y \beta^2 y = k y^2 $$ from which the condition $$ \beta = k^{1/3}$$ is derived.

Comment: What about , when k = -1? Aren't there multiple solutions?

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju -1 has only one real cube root right?

Answer (score 3):

Multiply both sides by $y'$ and integrate to get $y'^3=ky^3+C$. This integrates again to give a very ugly hypergeometric function (according to Wolfram alpha). So just hope your boundary conditions make C=0 to give An aedonist's solution.

Comment: Yes I was bewildered by that solution in wolfram Alpha.

Comment: Replace $C$ with $c^3$ it makes the solution look less ugly!